Derive the closed-form expression of Delannoy Numbers
I am trying to derive the closed-form expression of Delannoy Numbers, as the one in the wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delannoy_number#cite_note-7 
The closed-form expression looks like this: $$D(m,n)=\sum_{l=0}^{min(m,n)}\binom{m+n-l}{m}\binom{m}{l}$$
So I started from the recurrence relation: $D(m,n)=D(m-1,n)+D(m,n-1)+D(m-1,n-1)$ and solve the recurrence relation by using generating function.
This is what I had done so far:
\begin{align*}
  D(m,n)&=D(m-1,n)+D(m,n-1)+D(m-1,n-1)\\
        D(0,0)&=D(m,0)=D(0,n)=1\\
  G(x,y)&=\sum_{m,n\geq0}D(m,n) x^m y^n\\
  &=D(0,0)x^0 y^0 + \sum_{n>0}D(0,n)x^0 y^n +  \sum_{m>0} D(m,0)x^m y^0 + \sum_{m,n>0} D(m,n)x^m y^n\\
  &= 1 + \sum_{n>0} y^n + \sum_{m>0} x^m + \sum_{m,n>0} D(m,n)x^m y^n\\
  &= 1 + y\sum_{n\geq0} y^n + x\sum_{m\geq0} x^m + \sum_{m,n>0} [D(m-1,n)+D(m,n-1)+D(m-1,n-1)] x^m y^n\\
  &= 1 + y\sum_{n\geq0} y^n + x\sum_{m\geq0} x^m + \sum_{m,n>0} D(m-1,n)x^m y^n + \sum_{m,n>0} D(m,n-1)x^m y^n + \sum_{m,n>0} D(m-1,n-1)x^m y^n\\
  &= 1 + y\sum_{n\geq0} y^n + x\sum_{m\geq0} x^m + \sum_{\substack{m\geq0\\n>0}} D(m,n)x^{m+1} y^n + \sum_{\substack{m>0\\n\geq0}} D(m,n)x^m y^{n+1} + \sum_{m,n\geq0} D(m,n)x^{m+1} y^{n+1}\\
  &= 1 + y\sum_{n\geq0} y^n + x\sum_{m\geq0} x^m + x\bigg(\sum_{m,n\geq0}D(m,n) x^m y^n - \sum_{m\geq0}x^m\bigg) + y\bigg(\sum_{m,n\geq0}D(m,n) x^m y^n - \sum_{n\geq0}y^m\bigg)\\
  &+ xy\sum_{m,n\geq0}D(m,n) x^m y^n\\\\
  G(x,y)&=1+xG(x,y)+yG(x,y)+xy(Gx,y)\\
  G(x,y)&=\frac{1}{1-x-y-xy}
 \end{align*}
Let $z=x+y+xy$, then
\begin{align*}
   G(x,y)&=\frac{1}{1-(x+y+xy)}\\
   &=\frac{1}{1-z}\\
   &=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}z^k\\
   &=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(x+y+xy)^k\\
   &=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{i+j+l=k}\frac{k!}{i!j!l!}x^i y^j (xy)^l\\
   G(x,y)&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{i+j+l=k}\frac{k!}{i!j!l!}x^{i+l} y^{j+l}
 \end{align*}
Let $m=i+l$ and $n=j+l$, then
$$G(x,y)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{l=0}^{min(m,n)}\frac{(m+n-l)!}{(m-l)!(n-l)!l!}x^{m} y^{n}$$

I think I manage to get the closed-form expression for $D(m,n)$, but now I am stucked at the last step, where I need to write $G(x,y)$ as $G(x,y)=\sum_{m,n\geq0}D(m,n) x^m y^n$. How do I change the $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}$ into $\sum_{m,n\geq0}$?
Any help is appreciated! Thanks!
Update:
So I had done some computation using the $G(x,y)$ in my previous step above, trying to observe some pattern and here is the table:

So I observe that $l$ depends on $m$ and $n$, so we can ignore $l$ for now. And for every $k$, we can see that $m$ and $n$ takes value from $0$ to $k$, so as $k$ approach to $\infty$, $m$ and $n$ also approach $\infty$. Therefore, we can write the $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}$ part as $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}$.

Is this a valid argument?

Sorry my work looks a bit messy... It looks fine when I typed it in TexStudio, not sure why the equal signs are not aligned when I posted it here... TvT

What is $k$ in the last line ? How does it relate to the other variables ? It doesn't appear in the summand.

@Abezhiko i use $k$ when writing the closed form of $G(x,y)$ as a series, $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} z^k$ . Then I define $i+j+l=k=m+n-l$ by the multinomial theorem.

Should I use other variables like $m$ or $n$ when expanding the closed form of $G(x,y)$ as $\sum_{k} z^k$ ?

Initially, you have four variables, namely $(i,j,k,l)$, together with the constraint $i+j+l = k$, hence three "free" variables in practice. The said constraint becomes $m+n = k+l$ after the change of variables $m := i+l$ and $n := j+l$, with $l \le m,n \le k$, hence $0 \le l \le \min(m,n)$. Choosing $l$ as the first variable index, we may use $m$ and $n$ as the two other variables and finally $k = m+n-l$ as the fixed index. Note that $m$ and $n$ are bounded by $k$, which is itself unbounded, hence in the end :
$$
\sum_{k\ge0} \sum_{i+j+l=k} f(i,j,k,l) \equiv \sum_{m,n\ge0}\sum_{l=0}^{\min(m,n)} f(m-l,n-l,m+n-l,l)
$$

So we can directly write it as $\sum_{m, n\geq0}$. Thanks for the answer! :D

@ayamelon   You're welcome, I empathize with you on how the management of indices may produce a headache, but you did the most part of the work ;)
